# Why does this Python logical indexing take up so much memory

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I have a 1-D time series that is 1e8 long (100,000,000 elements). [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3eb6ywjzoo468rd/ch008.ddt) is a link to the data I am using on Dropbox. (The file is 382 MB.)

**Update**

Based on memory_profiling, the error occurs in the line

```
data[absolute(data-dc)< m*std(data)]=dc.
```

More specifically, the operation `absolute(data-dc)` eats up all the memory. `Data` is as described above and `dc` is  a constant. Perhaps this is a subtle syntax error?

I want to remove outliers and artifacts from it and replace those values with the median. I attempt to do that with the following function.

```
 from numpy import *

 from sys import argv

 from scipy.io import savemat
 from scipy.stats import scoreatpercentile

 def reject_outliers(data,dc,m=3):
      data[data==0] = dc
      data[bp.absolute(data-dc) < m*np.std(data)] = dc
      return data

 def butter_bandpass(lowcut,highcut,fs,order=8):
    nyq = 0.5*fs
    low = lowcut/nyq
    high = highcut/nyq

    b,a= butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b,a

 def butter_bandpass_filter(data,lowcut,highcut,fs,order=8):
    b,a = butter_bandpass(lowcut,highcut,fs,order=order)
    return lfilter(b,a,data) 

 OFFSET = 432
 filename = argv[1]
 outname = argv[2]  

 print 'Opening '+ filename
 with open(filename,'rb') as stream:
      stream.seek(OFFSET)
      data=fromfile(stream,dtype='int16')
 print 'Removing Artifacts, accounting for zero-filling'
 dc = median(data)
 data = reject_outliers(data,dc)

 threshold = scoreatpercentile(absolute(data),85)   
 print 'Filtering and Detrending'
 data = butter_bandpass_filter(data,300,7000,20000)
 savemat(outname+'.mat',mdict={'data':data})
```

Calling this on one file eats up 4 GB of RAM and 3 GB of virtual memory. I'm sure it's the second line of this function because I stepped through the script I wrote and it always hangs on this part. I can even see (in Finder on OS X) the available hard drive space plummeting by the second.

The time series is not long enough to explain it. What is wrong with the second line of `reject-outliers`?

Comment: you say calling this on one file, however, you dont show *how* you handle the file. I get this funny feeling you arent using an iterator, but instead, you are reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: @Ishpeck median is from numpy, post edited to reflect that.

Comment: @ITNinja I've edited the post to show how I load the file. It is a binary file with a 432 byte header that I don't need. The only thing after the header is the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory_profiler takes as memory for a line the  state of the Python virtual machine **after** the given line has been executed. Thus, arrays that are created and destroyed within a single line do not appear in the profile.

Taking @mbatchkarov's example, you can unroll the line "data[numpy.absolute(data-dc) < m*numpy.std(data)] = dc" into smaller chunks to see how the temporary arrays impact on memory:

```
from numpy.random import uniform
import numpy

@profile
def go(m=3):
    data = uniform(size=100000000)
    dc = numpy.median(data)
    t1 = data-dc
    t2 = numpy.absolute(t1) < m*numpy.std(data)
    data[t2] = dc
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    go()
```

which gives

```
$ python -m memory_profiler t1.py 
Filename: t1.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4                             @profile
     5     16.61 MB      0.00 MB   def go(m=3):
     6    779.56 MB    762.95 MB       data = uniform(size=100000000)
     7    779.62 MB      0.06 MB       dc = numpy.median(data)
     8   1542.57 MB    762.95 MB       t1 = data-dc
     9   1637.99 MB     95.42 MB       t2 = numpy.absolute(t1) < m*numpy.std(data)
    10   1638.00 MB      0.02 MB       data[t2] = dc
    11   1638.00 MB      0.00 MB       return data
```

Here it is clear that the "data-dc" instruction duplicates your memory layout. A workaround around this would be to perform the subtraction inplace, i.e. substitute "t1 = data - dc" by "data -= dc":

```
$ python -m memory_profiler t1.py 
Filename: t1.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4                             @profile
     5     16.61 MB      0.00 MB   def go(m=3):
     6    779.56 MB    762.95 MB       data = uniform(size=100000000)
     7    779.62 MB      0.06 MB       dc = numpy.median(data)
     8    779.63 MB      0.01 MB       data -= dc
     9    875.05 MB     95.42 MB       t2 = numpy.absolute(data) < m*numpy.std(data)
    10    875.07 MB      0.02 MB       data[t2] = dc
    11    875.07 MB      0.00 MB       return data
```

As you can see, "data -= dc" now barely increases memory.

Answer (score 5):

I just generated 100,000,000 random floats and did the same indexing you describe. Memory usage was well under a gigabyte throughout. What else is your code doing that you are not telling us about? Try running your code through the excellent [memory_profiler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).

---

Edit: Added code and output of memory_profiler:

```
from numpy.random import uniform
import numpy

@profile
def go(m=3):
    data = uniform(size=100000000)
    dc = numpy.median(data)
    data[numpy.absolute(data-dc) < m*numpy.std(data)] = dc
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    go()
```

Output:

```
Filename: example.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     3                             @profile
     4     15.89 MB      0.00 MB   def go(m=3):
     5    778.84 MB    762.95 MB    data = uniform(size=100000000)
     6    778.91 MB      0.06 MB    dc = numpy.median(data)
     7    874.34 MB     95.44 MB    data[numpy.absolute(data-dc) < m*numpy.std(data)] = dc
     8    874.34 MB      0.00 MB    return data
```

As you can see, 100M floats do not use up that much memory.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't. I'm trying to figure out my error. I can't run profiler because the file always eventually crashes my machine. It's weird- I can load this and similar data from the command line and plot it, etc fine.

Comment: If using the full data file crashes your machine, try running a profiler on a smaller data file. If you use unix, the `head` command should do it (unless your file is binary, in which case head might corrupt it)

Comment: Yeah, it's binary. The code runs fine for files that are under 150 MB.

Comment: Then profile using one of those files. It should give you an idea where your memory leak is.

Comment: The memory leak occurs when calculating `absolute(data-dc)`. I want to see how close all elements of data are to the constant dc. Is this not the right way? I checked the dc is indeed a scalar.

Answer (score 4):

Results for your data and modified [@mbatchkarov's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14688786/4279):

```
$ python mbatchkarov.py 
Filename: mbatchkarov.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5                             @profile
     6     15.74 MB      0.00 MB   def go(m=3):
     7     15.74 MB      0.00 MB       header_size = 432
     8     15.74 MB      0.00 MB       with open('ch008.ddt', 'rb') as file:
     9     15.75 MB      0.00 MB           file.seek(header_size)
    10    380.10 MB    364.36 MB           data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=np.int16) # 2 bytes per item                                                             
    11    380.20 MB      0.10 MB       dc = np.median(data)
    12                             
    13                                 # data[np.absolute(data - dc) < m*np.std(data)] = dc                                                                        
    14                                 # `data - dc` => temporary array 8 bytes per item                                                                           
    15    744.56 MB    364.36 MB       t = data.copy()
    16    744.66 MB      0.09 MB       t -= dc
    17    744.66 MB      0.00 MB       np.absolute(t, t)
    18    926.86 MB    182.20 MB       b = t < m*np.std(data) # boolean => 1 byte per item                                                                         
    19    926.87 MB      0.01 MB       data[b] = dc
    20    926.87 MB      0.00 MB       return data
```

`data - dc` would require several times more memory: 200M items x 8 bytes per item i.e., `data - dc` leads to creating of one or two temporary double arrays due to broadcasting. To avoid it, make an explicit copy and substruct inplace:

```
t = data.copy() # 200M items x 2 bytes per item
t -= dc
```

It seems `memory_profiler` doesn't show memory for temporary arrays. The max memory is around 3GB for the program.

Comment: `std` is also a huge bottleneck. I'll consider this an introduction to canonical problems in scientific computing.